# Invalid Content-Type for Netlify Dev forms request

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

I'm working on a Gatsby project with Netlify Functions locally using "netlify dev" on the CLI. Things were working relatively fine, I could go to localhost:8888 and get pages to appear and then I was trying to debug my functions. I got a message that the CLI needed to be updated, so I did, I ran again, made some very minor changes, but now I can't even get a single page to load!

I get the error in my console: "Invalid Content-Type for Netlify Dev forms request", every time I try to load a gatsby page. I can still access those pages in localhost:8000 however.

I'm not using Netlify forms at all, so not sure what this error is all of a sudden! Was it the CLI update, or somehow my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions `2.55.0` and `2.56.0` were published hours ago and have this issue. I just rolled back to `2.54.0` and the issue was fixed.